# get element in array item ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function writen in `ajax` that return a set of value:

```
$.each(data.dataa, function (i,item) {
    $.each(item, function (index, dat) {
        $str+=dat;
    })

    $ulSub.append( '<li id="'+item.id +'" class="ui-widget-content">' +$str+'</li>');
});
```

Each item has two attribute: the `id` and the `lastname`,
the value of each `$str` is a concatenation of the `id` and the `lastname`, but I want just the `lastname` not the `id`. I used the function `item[2]` but it's not working.

[image]

the result of my code is shwon as follow

[image]

What I want is just get the value of the `lasname`. I know that I should use `item.lastname`, but I want to ask if there are other methods to get the value of the lastname because the second attribute (lastname) is a variable.

Comment: In your `$.each(item`, check if `index` is the target variable's name, if it is, append the `dat` to the `$str`. Or `var target = 'lastname'; //whatever it is.`, then `$str += item[target]`;

Comment: There's no "second" element in a JavaScript object. They are unordered. Can you show a sample object (not a picture of one) that includes two different "second" properties, and the HTML you'd *like* to see as a result? Your desired output is very unclear at the moment.

Comment: What do you mean with "because the second attribute (lastname) is a variable"?

Comment: I've edited my code and show the result of it, as you see there are 1, 3 ,4 , 6 but I want just the second element (lastname). in others case, the lastname can be changed by name , phone or any other attribute from database, so I cani't use the method of item.lastname

Comment: How is it decided which data to return? You must request the data somehow.

Comment: @FelixKling I mean some time can be name, phone, adress, I execute my sql request  (select id, $field from contacts) and then sent the $field to ajax in my twig. so i haven't any khnowledge what the value of $field is.

Comment: Should it be only 2 attribute,  `id` and another desired one?

Comment: yes exactly , @fuyushimoya, the another desired one is variable, it can be lastname, name, adress, phonenumber .....

Comment: And at `js` side you know the field's name.

Comment: for(var key in item){  if(key != 'id'){$str+= item[key]} } should work

Comment: @fuyushimoya, no, I don't khnow the field's name,

Comment: Then changed a little in my first comment, check if `index` is not `'id'`, if it isn't, append `dat` to string.

Comment: @juvian woww worked great, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your case is quite simple, you always have an object with 2 properties: id and an unknown property. As objects do not have a defined order, you can´t assume that the field you want is always in second position

One way is to iterate the keys, and pick the one that is not equal to id:

```
for(var key in item){ 
    if(key != 'id'){
        $str+= item[key]
    } 
}
```

A similar way is to pick the object keys, and filter out the id one, then access the object with that key:

```
 $str+= item[Object.keys(item).filter(function(k){return k != 'id'})[0]]
```

If you know the possible values of the key, another way would be:

```
var possibleKeys = ['lastname', 'name', 'adress', 'phonenumber']

 for(var key in item){ 
    if(possibleKeys.indexOf(key) != -1){ // if its a valid key, append the value
        $str+= item[key]
    } 
}
```

In your case, the first option is probably the best, but there are mutiple ways to do it